# How to enable disable button on jqGrid row select

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have an input button like this:

```
<input type="button"
       id="deleteDocumentButton"
       value="Delete Document"
       class="btn"
       onclick="">
```

I want to disable this depending on if the following jqGrid's row is selected:

```
var encoded = '${JSONList}';
        var elem = document.createElement('textarea');
        elem.innerHTML = encoded;
        var decoded = elem.value;
        var parsed = JSON.parse(decoded);

        var values = parsed.values
        jQuery("#existingDocs").jqGrid({
          data: values,
          datatype: "local",
          height: 'auto',
          colNames:['Filename','Description'],
          colModel:[
            {name:'filenameAndPath',index:'filenameAndPath', width:400, sorttype:"string"},
            {name:'description',index:'description', width:400, sorttype:"string"},
          ],
          viewrecords: true,
          caption: "Exisitng User Docs"
         });
```

I have tried this solution but it throws the error: `Cannot property of length on undefined()`:

```
 var selRow = jQuery("#exisitingDocs").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrow');
     var count = selRow.length;
      if(count >0)
      {
        $('#deleteDocumentButton').prop('disabled', false);
      }
      else{
        $('#deleteDocumentButton').prop('disabled', true);
      }
```

Am I missing some logic or else how do I solve this issue?

Comment: What do mean by selected? The line `jQuery("#exisitingDocs").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrow');` will only return a non undefined value when the select checkbox is checked if you have `multiselect:true`.

Comment: I have changed `selarrow` to `selrow`. It still seems to have the same error. By selected I mean the current highlighted row in the grid

Comment: Can you not use event `onSelectRow: function(rowid, status, e) {//disable button code }` instead?
More on jqGrid events [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events).

Comment: Tried the following:

Comment: `$('#deleteDocumentButton').prop('disabled', true);
        jQuery("#existingDocs")
              .jqGrid({

              onSelectRow: function(rowid, status, e) {
                    $('#deleteDocumentButton').prop('disabled', false);
               }

        });`

Comment: Button is now always disabled :(

Comment: Try adding condition `if(status) {//disable button}` in `onSelectRow`.

Comment: Have implemented this 
` jQuery("#existingDocs")
              .jqGrid({
              onSelectRow: function(rowid, status, e) {
                console.log(rowid);
                    if(status){
                        $('#deleteDocumentButton').prop('disabled',false);
                    }else{
                        $('#deleteDocumentButton').prop('disabled', true);
                    }
               }

        }); `

Comment: There is still no change to the state of the button. The console.log is also not showing up so I'm guessing this function is not being called :(